# Scrapy with pdfkit, Winerror 206

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pdfkit

Below is the programme I am trying to run, but it returns Winerror 206, is it some sort of windows bug or something else! I found Winerror 206 is something regarding sobprocess, Can anyone help me solve this?

```
import pdfkit
import scrapy

path = r"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path)

class WorkRegister(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "WorkRegister_PartB"
    start_urls = ['http://127.0.0.1:5500/sripur.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        trees = response.xpath('//div[3]//div[2]/table//tr')
        all_links = []
        for tree in trees:
            if (tree.xpath('.//td[6]/text()').get()).strip()=="Gram Panchayat":
                print('true...............')
                front_url = 'https://mnregaweb2.nic.in/netnrega/'
                scraped_link = str(tree.xpath('.//td[2]/a/@href').get())
                new_url = f"{front_url}{scraped_link}"
                all_links.append(new_url)

        
        print(all_links)
        pdfkit.from_url(all_links, r"./register4_Part_B.pdf", configuration=config)
        # pdfkit.from_url(all_links, "D:\Documents\Register_4_Part_B\register4_Part_B.pdf", configuration=config)
```

The error is as follows

```
2022-05-28 10:41:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/sripur.html> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 857, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 67, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\Register_4_Part_B\pdfcreator.py", line 29, in parse
    pdfkit.from_url(all_links, r"./register4_Part_B.pdf", configuration=config)
  File "C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 27, in from_url
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 169, in to_pdf
    result = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long
2022-05-28 10:41:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution. The problem was number of characters I was passing in arguments, it exceeded the argument character limit of windows(which is something 32k+), I used URL shortener to reduce the number of characters pass in arguments and it worked.
Below is the new code. Thanks Everyone.

```
from socket import timeout
import pyshorteners
import pdfkit
import scrapy

path = r"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf = path)
options = {'page-size': 'A4'}

class WorkRegister(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "WorkRegister_PartB"
    start_urls = ['http://127.0.0.1:9112/sripur2021.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        trees = response.xpath('//div[3]//div[2]/table//tr')
        all_links = []
        for tree in trees:
            if (tree.xpath('.//td[6]/text()').get()).strip()=="Gram Panchayat":
                print('true...............')
                front_url = 'https://mnregaweb2.nic.in/netnrega/'
                scraped_link = str(tree.xpath('.//td[2]/a/@href').get())
                new_url = f"{front_url}{scraped_link}"
                shortener = pyshorteners.Shortener(timeout=120)
                shortened_url = shortener.tinyurl.short(new_url)
                all_links.append(shortened_url)

        print(all_links)
        pdfkit.from_url(all_links, r"./Sripur_20-21_register4_Part_B.pdf", configuration=config, options=options)
```